# Combining two words into a name

Tags: definitions, names

I've noticed that Japanese names are often made up of different words meaning different things, creating a combination of the meaning of the Japanese name.

Is it possible if I could combine two words, himitsu 秘密 (secret) and sora 空 (sky), into one name? I'm trying to create a name meaning both "secret" and "sky"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible if I could combine two words, himitsu 秘密 (secret) and sora 空 (sky), into one name?

Yes, it is.
In this case, I would make up a name with 秘空{ひくう}.
Usually we use two *kanji*s, not three, to make up a name, so 秘空 is better than 秘密空.
And 秘 itself means 秘密, so you can use 秘 instead of 秘密 safely in 秘空.

## BONUS

As you know, 空 has two meanings: (1) sky; (2) empty/vacant, so I recommend that you would choose 天 instead of 空 for the meaning of sky.
Now you would get the name as 秘天｛ひてん｝. I think it's a wonderful name having the meaning with secret and sky. By the way, 天 has two meanings: (1) sky; (2) heaven.

Comment: 飛天にすると、https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%A3%9B%E5%A4%A9%E5%BE%A1%E5%89%A3%E6%B5%81に思わせるではないか。

Comment: @virmaior これですか？→　https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/飛天御剣流

Comment: First thing that came to mind was 密空【みつあき】, but as you said, that's the wrong reading for 空... Maybe 空密【そらみ】 is a reasonable (female) name?

Comment: @Earthling: 質問者が何の名前を尋ねているのか分かりません。もし、人の名前あるいは女性の名前を尋ねているのであれば、空密｛そらみ｝は、秘天｛ひてん｝より響き（＝発音したときの感じ）が良いので優れた名前だと思います。